# Spring Data returning null values from database after saving entity

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a marketplace system, so I have Cart entity, which has a List of Items, in a ManyToOne relantionship. Problem is: a want to, as soon as I save a new Item, calculate the total cost of the Cart through the Product entity, which is present in Item.

Then I send the ItemDTO containing only cartId and productId and save this entity.
After that, I get all Carts from database, but the new Item I just created comes with null productPrice and productName.

I don't understand this behaviour, because since the entities are mapped correctly and I am recovering the data from database, all fields should be filled.

I will leave the code below.

Product class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
    
@Column(length = 40)
@NotBlank(message = "Field name cannot be blank!")
private String name;
    
@Column(precision = 2)
@NotNull(message = "Field price cannot be null!")
private Double price;
    
@NotNull(message = "Field stock cannot be null!")
private Integer stock;
```

Item class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_product")
@NotNull(message = "Field product cannot be null!")
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_cart")
@NotNull(message = "Field cart cannot be null!")
private Cart cart;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_purchase")
private Purchase purchase;

@NotNull(message = "Field quantity cannot be null!")
private Integer quantity;
```

Cart class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
private List<Item> items;

private Double totalPrice;


public Double calculateTotalPrice() {
    List<Double> itemsPrice = items.stream().map(item -> item.getProduct().getPrice() * item.getQuantity()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.totalPrice = itemsPrice.stream().reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
    System.out.println(this.totalPrice);
    return itemsPrice.stream().reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
}
```

ItemDTO class:

```
public class ItemDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer productId;
    private String productName;
    private Integer productStock;
    private Double productPrice;
    private Integer cartId;
    private Integer quantity;
    
}
```

saveItem method, in ItemService:

```
public ItemDTO saveItem(ItemDTO itemDTO) {
        Item item = mapper.map(itemDTO, Item.class);
        item = itemRepository.save(item);
        CartDTO cartDTO = cartService.getCartById(item.getCart().getId());
        Cart cart = mapper.map(cartDTO, Cart.class);
        cart.calculateTotalPrice();
        cartDTO = mapper.map(cart, CartDTO.class);
        cartService.updateCart(cartDTO);
        return itemDTO;
    }
```

And the JSON I'm sending through Postman is in this format:

```
{
    "cartId": 1,
    "productId": 3,
    "quantity": 1
}
```

Well, hope you can understand my doubt and help me. Thank you.

Comment: Because they don`t present in json command and not initialized by default in dto

Comment: Yes, but I pass an existent productId to ItemDTO, save it in database and then retrieve the data from db. It should relate the tables and bring back all the data from Product, not only the attributes I passed in JSON. If I call findById outside the method save after saving the Item, it doesn't return null attributes like before, so I'm guessing it is some behaviour of Spring in dealing with entities.